# Pandas get N rows around a boolean index match

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

consider the following

```
import pandas

data = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15,18,19])

diffs = data.diff()
# [NaN,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,3,1]
```

now i want to get all the pairs around the gaps greater than 1

`data[diffs > 1]` will give me [12,18]

but **i really want**

```
[6,7,12,13],
[14,15,18,19]
```

so i can do things with shift but that seems so wrong, that it's basically not even a solution

```
masked_around = ((diffs > 1)| (diffs.shift(-1) > 1) | (diffs.shift(-2) > 1) | (diffs.shift(1) > 1))
data[masked_around]
```

and that basically gives me what i need but it seems like very much the wrong way to say give me `data[match_index-3:match_index+1]`

Comment: Smear the mask?

Comment: that sounds right

Comment: Except you couldn't quite split the data every nth element because you'd have to check if the first element was too close to the edge.

Comment: Hang on, I'll draft something based on numpy.

Comment: I think we can achieve this by for loop

Comment: Do you just need one mask for the original Series? Or do you really need those two sets of lists? Your really want and your attempted solution, which you admit works, seem to be different.

Comment: either would work ... (WRT one or two ... but i would like to get two) @WeNYoBen ... its a very very large DataFrame ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the potential solution

```
idx=data.index[data.diff() > 1]

[data.iloc[x : min(y+1, data.index.max()+1)].tolist() for x , y in zip(idx-2, idx+1)]
Out[34]: [[6, 7, 12, 13], [14, 15, 18, 19]]
```